# Pymongo error for ArrayFilters to update multiple subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

My query is regarding update multiple subdocuments stored in array forms.

Environment : I have installed MongoDB shell version v3.6.3, python 3.6.9, and pymongo 3.6.1 in my computer.

**Schema sample :**

```
dept : { "_id" : 1, "dept_name" : "paper", "dept_projs" : 2534, "dept_city" : "Pimpri-Chinchwad",
 "emps": [
         { "salary" : 10000, "city" : "Ajmer", "_id" : 1111, "emp_name" : "Jessica Ali" } ,
         { "salary" : 12000, "city" : "Dhanbad", "_id" : 1112, "emp_name" : "Samuel Sanchez" },
         { "salary" : 8000, "city" : "Gwalior", "_id" : 1113, "emp_name" : "Willie Little" } ,
        ...
          ]
}
```

**Query : I would like to update selected multiple subdocuments stored in array. When I write this query in mongodb cell, it works. But, Python3 shows me error.**

```py
db.dept.update({"emps._id":{"$gte":1111,"$lte":1114}},{"$inc":{"emps.$[idx].salary" : 20000}},{"arrayFilters":[{"idx._id":{"$gte":1111, "$lte":1114}}],multi:true})
```

Error: `"TypeError: upsert must be True or False"`

for Python code
**result

```py
E=db.dept.update({"emps._id":{"$gte":1111,"$lte":1114}},{"$inc":{"emps.$[idx].salary" :20000}},{"arrayFilters":[{"emps._id":{"$gte":1111,"$lte":1114}}],"multi":True})**
```

Error:`pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: BSON field 'update.updates.multi' is the wrong type 'object', expected type 'bool'`

for python code
**result

```py
E=db.dept.update({"emps._id":{"$gte":1111,"$lte":1114}},{"$inc":{"emps.$[idx].salary" : 20000}},False, True,{"arrayFilters":[{"emps._id":{"$gte":1111,"$lte":1114}}]})**
```

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the source code of `pymongo`, you will find that the `update` function won't receive any parameter about `arrayFilters`, so you have to use `update_one`, which would accept a optional parameter named `array_filters`:

```
db.dept.update_one(
    {"emps._id" : {"$gte" : 1111, "$lte" : 1114}},
    {"$inc" : {"emps.$[idx].salary" : 20000}}, 
    upsert=True,
    array_filters=[{"idx._id" : {"$gte" : 1111,  "$lte"  : 1114}}]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rather write your request like this:

```
db.dept.update({"emps._id" : {"$gte" : 1111, "$lte" : 1114}}, {"$inc" : {"emps.$[idx].salary" : 20000}}, {"arrayFilters" : [{"idx._id" : {"$gte" : 1111,  "$lte"  : 1114}}], multi=True})
```

Note: I have provided a syntax correction only, which is related to the question on the ArrayFilters in pymongo.