# Updating nested MongoDB collection (Pymongo)

Tags: python, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

-EDIT-

How can I update a nested collection using Pymongo based on more than 1 condition?

My document looks like this:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('613eb154aee899694f934259'),
  'company': 
      [{'name': 'Flower shop', 
        'persons': 
            [{'personId': '1000',
              'personIdType': 'Passport/Others'},
             {'personId': '3000',
              'personIdType': 'Passport/Others'}
            ]}
      ]}
]
```

I want to **update the personId 1000 to 2000**. Therefore the 2 conditions are: objectId = '613eb154aee899694f934259' AND the personId = 1000

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `$set` to set the `personId` field. You will need `arrayFilter` to specifiy the filtering condition for the array.

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: ObjectId("613eb154aee899694f934259")
},
{
  $set: {
    "company.$[].persons.$[p].personId": 2000
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "p.personId": "1000"
    }
  ]
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Uq4cbhqQz1Z) for your reference.

Comment: Hi Ray, thank you so much. It works when there is 1 record or personId. However, how can I go about it when I have more than one condition to test for? I have edited the question. Thank you again.

Comment: @Ry123 updated the solution to use `arrayFilter`. You will find this very useful when you have to work a lot with arrays.

Comment: I tried the method but it showed me an error: ` TypeError: upsert must be True or False. I added `upsert = True` as the last argument of the `update` function and I got `TypeError: update() got multiple values for argument 'upsert'`. Are there any alternate ways for this?

Comment: @Ry123 [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65277594/14732669) could be what you are looking for

Comment: @ray, your answer is correct, it's just that you have to convert the code to python since `arrayFilters` works in a different way in python. Upvoted your answer

Answer (score 2):

[@ray's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14732669/ray) answer is correct. But you have to convert his solution to python.

Below answer is the exact replication of [@ray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14732669/ray) answer converted in python.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId


col = MongoClient()["temp"]["tmp9"]

col.update_many({
  "_id": ObjectId("613eb154aee899694f934259"),
}, {
  "$set": {
    "company.$[].persons.$[p].personId": "2000",
  }
},
  array_filters=[{"p.personId": "1000"}]
)
```

Comment: Sorry that I am still on my way to adapt the pymongo syntax from the native query that I am familiar with. Many thanks @hhharsha35 for this short, concise and high-quality answer :)

Comment: Thank you both @ray and hhharsha36, the answers have been really helpful. It works perfectly fine.